# How do I save a modified web page that was loaded in a DotNetBrowser control?

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I just want a simple one page HTML dump from the current DOM that contains the html tags and everything between.

I've tried using SavePageType variations and none of them do what I need.

When I use SavePageType.COMPLETE_HTML, it makes a mess of the html and changes all the resource links and downloads the resources which I don't want.

I can't use the SavePageType.MHTML option.

When I use SavePageType.ONLY_HTML, it saves perfectly but it doesn't save the changes that were made to the DOM which is odd.

I also tried getting the html element but GetElementByTagName can't find it. The html, head and body tags are also missing even though it provides what's inside those tags which is really weird.

Is there a way to capture the modified html (without problems) using DotNetBrowser?

Answer (score 1):

It's Eugene here. I work with the team which created DotNetBrowser.

If I understood correctly, you need to save the modified HTML content of the web page you have loaded.

In this case, you can obtain the current HTML using the `Browser.GetHTML()` method and then save it to the file using the `File.WriteAllText()` method. The following source code demonstrates how to do this:

```
string html = browser.GetHTML();
File.WriteAllText("path/to/file.html", html);
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Sorry for the delay. Had to get back into the swing of things after the holidays. :) Your solution seems to be working perfectly. Don't know why I missed it.